# Using renderd on OSM tile server?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik

I followed [this tutorial](https://ircama.github.io/osm-carto-tutorials/tile-server-ubuntu/) and have some troubles. When I restart and get status of the renderd service, I get the following error :

```
renderd[8162]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Postgis Plugin: missing <table> parameter  encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover-low-zoom' in Layer at line 755 of '/home/anne/src/openstreetmap-carto/style.xml
```

It doesn't seems anyone else got the same error as me, I double-checked my renderd config file and the path to mapnik plugin seems to be correct :

```bash
user@comp:~$ mapnik-config --input-plugins
/usr/local/lib/mapnik/input
```

And in the renderd file:

```
[mapnik]
plugins_dir=/usr/local/lib/mapnik/input
font_dir=/usr/share/fonts
font_dir_recurse=true
```

Comment: hi, I saw your question about polygon and mysql. I'm solving a similar problem. I have a page on which I have a Leaflet.Draw plugin and I want to save the lines to mysql database. All day I sit on it and can't think of any way. How to save and display it on the map again. Could you please advise me. I'd be very grateful.
My way is that after drawing the line the coordinates are transferred to the form field, which is then sent to the database. But I have a problem that I save the coordinates twice and at the end of the database I am not able to write php to give it usable json.

Answer (score 1):

What that error message is trying to tell you is that something hasn't been set up properly.

Have a look at line 755 of '/home/anne/src/openstreetmap-carto/style.xml and see what it says.  It'll be doing something with a 'landcover-low-zoom' layer, and the chances are that that'll give you a clue what you didn't set up.

Also have a look at https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/blob/master/INSTALL.md , which is the latest installation instructions for the OSM Carto style, in case anything has changed.

Yet another place to look is https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-18-04-lts/ - that is trying to do the same job as Ircama's page, but explains things differently, so maybe that might help too.